# How to use foreach and if statement within array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, foreach

I'm developing a [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) plugin and using [Tareq's WordPress Settings API](https://github.com/tareq1988/wordpress-settings-api-class) to develop my settings page.

With the API, I am displaying checkbox items. However, I want to show additional checkboxes using the `foreach` and `if` statement.

- `foreach`: this will display additional checkboxes for every field in the [`wp_get_user_contact_methods()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_user_contact_methods/)
- `if`: this will display an extra set of checkboxes if another plugin is activated

This is what I have right now going off of my own logic:

```
$settings_fields = array( // Parent array
    'dsbl_basics' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'text_val',
            'label' => __( 'Text Input', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => 'Title',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'intval'
        )
    ),
    'dsbl_profile' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __( 'Name', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'first_name' => 'First Name',
                'last_name' => 'Last Name'
            )
        ),
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'contact_info',
            'label' => __( 'Contact Info', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'url' => 'Website',
                foreach ( wp_get_user_contact_methods() as $value => $label ) { // Additional contact fields
                    $value => $label
                }
            )
        ),
        if ( is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) { // If plugin exists
            array( // Child's child array
                'name' => 'yoast_seo',
                'label' => __( 'Yoast SEO', 'dsbl' ),
                'type' => 'multicheck',
                'options' => array(
                    'wpseo_author_title' => 'Title to use for Author page',
                    'wpseo_author_metadesc' => 'Meta description to use for Author page'
                )
            ),
        }
    )
);
```

I know that my syntax is off which is giving me these errors:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected `foreach` (T_FOREACH), expecting `)`
>
> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected `if` (T_IF), expecting `)`

What is the proper approach to this?

Comment: .... Don't put foreach and if clauses inside of your array, that's not how it works.

Comment: @Epodax Instead of telling me what I cannot do, may you explain what else I could do to achieve the same results?

Comment: Move your foreach and if clause out of your array, assign the values from your foreach / if clause to variables and use those variables in your large array. - Please don't just throw code together and expect us to fix it.

Comment: @Epodax As you can see, I am not pasting my code and asking to _do it for me_. I am asking for the right approach to it since and I provide the code on what I am doing. Please, be more considerate when someone is asking for advice.

Comment: The right approach is to try and fix it yourself and when you have tried to fix it you come to SO and ask for help, in your question you show us what you have tried in order to fix the issue and why / what isn't working with the attempt you've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$contactArray = [];
foreach ( wp_get_user_contact_methods() as $value => $label ) { 
    $contactArray[$value] = $label;
}
$contactArray['url'] = 'Website';

$settings_fields = array( // Parent array
    'dsbl_basics' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'text_val',
            'label' =>  'Text Input',
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => 'Title',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'intval'
        )
    ),
    'dsbl_profile' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => 'dsbl',
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'first_name' => 'First Name',
                'last_name' => 'Last Name'
            )
        ),
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'contact_info',
            'label' => 'Contact Info', 
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => $contactArray
        )
    )
);

$yaostSEO = array( // Child's child array
    'name' => 'yoast_seo',
    'label' => 'Yoast SEO', 
    'type' => 'multicheck',
    'options' => array(
        'wpseo_author_title' => 'Title to use for Author page',
        'wpseo_author_metadesc' => 'Meta description to use for Author page'
    )
);

if ( is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) {
    $settings_fields['dsbl_profile'][] = $yaostSEO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put foreach statements (nor while, for, do or any loop or control structure if/else) as array value or anywhere within array. Where that idea came from anyway? Something like this should do.

```
$settings_fields = array( // Parent array
    'dsbl_basics' => array( // Child array
        0 => array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'text_val',
            'label' => __( 'Text Input', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => 'Title',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'intval'
        )
    ),
    'dsbl_profile' => array( // Child array
        0 => array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __( 'Name', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'first_name' => 'First Name',
                'last_name' => 'Last Name'
            )
        ),
        1 => array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'contact_info',
            'label' => __( 'Contact Info', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'url' => 'Website',
                /* this isn't place for loops */
            )
        )
    )
);


if ( is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) 
{   // If plugin exists
    $settings_fileds['dsbl_profile'][2]  =  array( // Child's child array
        'name' => 'yoast_seo',
        'label' => __( 'Yoast SEO', 'dsbl' ),
        'type' => 'multicheck',
        'options' => array(
            'wpseo_author_title' => 'Title to use for Author page',
            'wpseo_author_metadesc' => 'Meta description to use for Author page'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I added numbers, as that's what's PHP it self is doing when there are no keys, just values. Empty keys are actually numerical keys, hence we don't need to type them, nonetheless, php will add and parse them automatically. If You want to become good at what You do (php in this case) here > http://php.net/manual/en/index.php 
Good luck.